# Combinations of numbers in array who sum is equal to n

Tags: javascript, combinatorics

Example:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

I want to display all of the unique 3 number combinations in the array where the sum of those 3 digits is equal to 9 (or n).

So result in this example would be:

```
[1,2,6]
[2,3,4]
[1,3,5]
```

Closest thing I could find was permutations of a string...

```
var alphabet = "abcde"; // shortened to save time

function permute(text) {
if(text.length === 3) { // if length is 3, combination is valid; alert
    console.log(text); // or alert
} else {
    var newalphabet = alphabet.split("").filter(function(v) {
        return text.indexOf(v) === -1;
    }); // construct a new alphabet of characters that are not used yet
        // because each letter may only occur once in each combination

    for(var i = 0; i < newalphabet.length; i++) {
        permute(text + newalphabet[i]); // call permute with current text + new
                                        // letter from filtered alphabet
    }
  }
}

permute("");
```

Comment: I'm not really a coder, just hacking away at other people's stuff.  The closest thing I could find was permutations of a string, added above.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible solution. Please note it does not take care of unique values and for that you need to add additional logic. However, if the array is sorted and have unique entries then the following will be producing the ideal result.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length-2; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j< a.length-1;j++) {
    for (var k = j+1; k < a.length;k++) {
      if(a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 9) {
         result.push([a[i],a[j], a[k]]);
      } 
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```